# Fix for uniform button border-radius

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

http://codepen.io/mochiii/full/NGMXpe/ i have this project my problem is that the border- radius of the buttons are not uniform how do i fix that. I already tried specifying order radius for individual buttons but does not work.

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Audiowide);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Righteous);

body{
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.header{
  font-family: 'Righteous', cursive;  
}

h1{
  border: 3px solid #ffffff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}
.countdown-block{
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

#clock{
  border: 50px solid #FF1919;
  border-radius: 60px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 370px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
#clock>#countdown{
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: 'Audiowide', cursive;
}

.breakHeader, .timeHeader{
  font-family: 'Righteous', cursive;
}

#break, #time{
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'Audiowide', cursive;
}

.btn{
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: 'Righteous', cursive;
  transition: all .3s;
  position: absolute;

}

.btn:hover{
  font-size: 35px;
}

.btn-group{
  position: relative;
  height: 35px;
  display: block;
}

.btn-group > .btn{
  float: none;
}

footer{
  margin-top: 80px;
  border-top: 2px dashed #ffffff;
}
```

i wonder what should i do thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "not uniform"?

Comment: i want it to be all same border radius as you can see with the buttons the outer edges only has the border radius

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you use Bootstrap and if you use `.btn-group` Bootstrap has predefined styles for that (you can see it [HERE](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups)).

You can either override Bootstrap styles or create your own custom class and apply `border-radius` to it.

First solution:

CSS:

```
.btn-group>.btn:first-child:not(:last-child):not(.dropdown-toggle) {
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.btn-group>.btn:not(:first-child):not(:last-child):not(.dropdown-toggle) {
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.btn-group>.btn:last-child:not(:first-child), .btn-group>.dropdown-toggle:not(:first-child) {
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

### [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bVKbVX)

Second solution:

HTML:

Add `your-border-radius` class to every button

```
<button class="btn btn-success your-border-radius" id="countdownStart">Start</button>
```

CSS:

```
.your-border-radius {
  border-radius: 10px !important;
}
```

You have to use [`!important`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception) rule to override Bootstrap styles.

### [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EVRYKX)

Comment: oh i see thanks for pointing it out i understood now! thanks such a big help :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with you implementation of bootstrap.min.   There is a Button Group that removed border radius.  What you can do is overwrite these classes by changing the order of the css class implementation.  Then over write the classes for whatever you want.

.btn-group>.btn:first-child:not(:last-child):not(.dropdown-toggle) {
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}